# I can't get a Bluetrade API Private Function Call to Work

Tags: .net, vb.net, api

Here is their PHP Examaple. You can find the entire api at https://bleutrade.com/help/API

```
$apikey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
$apisecret = 'YOUR_API_SECRET';
$nonce = time();
$uri = 'https://bleutrade.com/api/v2/account/getbalances?                        
apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign = hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign)); // you can 
add the signature at the end of the uri if you prefer: &apisign=...
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

Below is my VB Code

```
    Dim sApiKey As String = "Enter API Key"
    Dim sApiSecret As String = "Enter API Secret Key"

    Dim sURI As String = "https://bleutrade.com/api/v2/account/getbalances?apikey=" + sApiKey
    Dim secretkey() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sApiSecret)
    Dim uri() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sURI)
    Dim myhmac As New HMACSHA512(secretkey)
    Dim bSign As Byte() = myhmac.ComputeHash(uri)
    Dim wrGETURL As WebRequest

    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURI)
    wrGETURL.Headers.Add("apsign:" & Convert.ToBase64String(bSign))
    Dim objStream As Stream
    objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream()

    Dim objReader As New StreamReader(objStream)
    Dim sLine As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do While Not sLine Is Nothing
        i += 1
        sLine = objReader.ReadLine
        If Not sLine Is Nothing Then

        End If
    Loop
```

I'm getting the error {"success":"false","message":"Invalid apikey or apisecret","result":[]}

I have already tried getting a new api key twice.

Thanks a trillion for whatever wisdom you can throw my way.

Answer (score 0):

`wrGETURL.Headers.Add("apsign:" & Convert.ToBase64String(bSign))`

Try spelling `apisign` correctly. Also, I don't think you need to base64 encode it, just HEX encode it instead.